# Error while adding ContextHub to the page component

Tags: aem

We are working on the AEM 6.3.

We have used Context Hub Parameters on Adobe Target Framework within Adobe Target cloud configuration.

However, when we have add the following line to add ContextHub to our page component:

**sly data-sly-resource="${'contexthub' @ resourceType='granite/contexthub/components/contexthub'}"/>**

I am getting error on the console as shown below:
[image]

I tried resolving this but the effort was in vain.

Can anyone help me regarding this ?

Do we need to add some dependency for ContextHub in our clientlibs?

Thanks !

Comment: `/etc/cloudsettings/default/contexthub.kernel.js` contains the function  `injectContextHubUI` that seems to be missing on your page. Can you access it directly from your browser? Has the "ContextHub Path" been set in your page properties? If not, it should be set to "/etc/cloudsettings/default/contexthub".

Comment: Yes the ContextHub Path property is set to the page.

Comment: Got the problem solved.
We need to add embed property in our clientlibs with these values:
1. jquery
2. granite.utils
3. granite.jquery
4. cq.jquery
5. cq.wcm.foundation
6. cq.wcm.foundation-main
 
Thanks !

Comment: @SaumyaJain can you update your question with the answer?

Answer (score 2):

add the following clientlibs to your website and the error would go away.

granite.utils and granite.jquery

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Add this line also where you are including contexthub

```
data-sly-call="${clientlib.js @ categories='granite.utils'}
```